# Proving $\arg(zw)=\arg(z)+\arg(w)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

This is my attempt I know this is incomplete or may even be wrong.

Let $θ_1 \in \arg(z)$ and $θ_2 \in \arg(w)$. Then, $θ_1+θ_2 \in \arg(z)+\arg(w)$.

Also, $θ_1+θ_2 \in \arg(zw)$. Is this sufficient for the proof or correct at all? Hope someone could help me out. Thanks.

EDIT: Just to avoid any confusions I will add how $\arg z$ is defined.

$\arg z=\{\text{Arg}\, z+2\pi k\mid k\text{ is an integer}\}$

Comment: Why use $\in$ instead of $=$ ?

Comment: @Winther: Presumably because it makes the statement true? (If you define $\operatorname{arg}(z)$ to be the set of all possible arguments of $z$.)

Answer (score 2):

Let $z=r_1 e^{i \theta_1}$ and $w=r_2 e^{i \theta_2}$, then
$
zw=r_1 r_2 e^{i (\theta_1+\theta_2)}.
$
Hence
$$
\arg(z)=\theta_1 + 2k\pi, k\in \mathbf{Z}\\
\arg(w)=\theta_2+2k\pi, k\in \mathbf{Z}\\
\arg(zw)=\theta_1+\theta_2+2k\pi, k\in \mathbf{Z}.
$$
There it is: $\arg(zw)=\arg(z)+\arg(w)$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a proof: Let $z=r e^{i\theta}$  and $w=s e^{i\phi}$. Then $$\text{Arg}(zw)=\text{Arg}\left(rse^{i\theta}e^{i\phi}\right)=\text{Arg}\left(rse^{i(\theta+\phi)}\right)=\text{Arg}(z)+\text{Arg}(w)\quad(\text{mod }2\pi),$$
 where $\text{Arg}(z)\in[0,2\pi)$ is the principal argument of $z$.

However, as Micah commented above, it looks like you're considering sets of all arguments, i.e. to obtain all representations, $$z=re^{i(\theta + 2\pi n)}$$ and $$w=se^{i(\phi+2\pi m)},$$ where $n,m\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Since $\arg(-1+i)=3\pi/4$ and $(-1+i)^2=-2i$, your answer means that $\arg(-2i)=3\pi/4+3\pi/4=3\pi/2$? I thought that $\arg(-i)$ was equal to $-\pi/2$. Please explain.

Comment: I think that fixes it, but I'm sure you will throw another spanner my way @ Did.

Comment: If arguments are in $[0,2\pi)$, try $z=w=-i$. (But I am surprised, do you still think your computations are rigorous?)

Comment: In that case, $\text{Arg}(-i)=3\pi/2$, and so $\text{Arg}(-i)+\text{Arg}(-i)=3\pi\equiv \pi$. But $\text{Arg}(-i\times-i)=\text{Arg}(-1)=\pi$. This is correct given arguments in $[0,2\pi)$.

Comment: Sorry but this won't do: your answer does state that **the usual sum** of the arguments is the argument of the sum.

Comment: The principal argument is a well known concept. What do you mean by **the usual sum**?

Comment: Ahhh... Your last edit signals that you finally saw there is a problem.

Comment: Ah, yes I was always aware of that problem but I was only ever considering principal arguments. I think I just limited the scope of the question which wouldn't do as you quite rightly said.

Comment: One last try and I will leave it at that: *even when one considers principal arguments*, the argument of the sum is not always the sum of the arguments.

Comment: I think that last edit should get across what I actually mean.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure we can use the $w = e^{i\theta{}_w}$ here because this is a notation that is partially induced from what he is trying to prove. Here's a proof that doesn't need this.

So we have $\text{arg}(w) \in \theta{}_w$ and $\text{arg}(z) \in \theta{}_z$.

This means $w = |w|(\cos{\theta{}_w}+\sin{\theta{}_w})$ and $z = |z|(\cos{\theta{}_z}+\sin{\theta{}_z})$.

By multiplication : $wz = |{w}| |{z}| ((\cos \theta_w \cos \theta_z - \sin \theta_w \sin \theta_z) + i (\cos \theta_w \sin \theta_z + \sin \theta_w \cos \theta_z))$ which happens to be equal to $|{w}| |{z}| (\cos (\theta_w + \theta_z) + i \sin (\theta_w + \theta_z)).$

Hence, noting $wz = x + iy$ and identifying the real and the imaginary part, we have $\dfrac x {|wz|} = \cos (\theta_w + \theta_z)$ and $\dfrac y {|wz|} = \sin (\theta_w + \theta_z)$.

This is the definition of $(\theta_w + \theta_z)$ belonging to $\text{arg}(wz)$.

Comment: Since $\arg(-1+i)=3\pi/4$ and $(-1+i)^2=-2i$, your answer means that $\arg(-2i)=3\pi/4+3\pi/4=3\pi/2$? I thought that $\arg(-i)$ was equal to $-\pi/2$. Please explain.

Comment: @Did Yes, $-i$ and $-2i$ have the same argument. Draw them on the complex plane. E: Wait, there's another discussion on a comment with same content (by Did) in a different answer. :confused:

Comment: I think he's misunderstanding why $3\pi/2$ and $-\pi/2$ are not different arguments?

Comment: @Nishant You think I am misunderstanding... what, exactly?

Comment: Oh, I thought you were confused as to why two things that have the same argument have the numbers $-\pi/2$ and $3pi/2$ as arguments?

Comment: @Nishrt You might want to read carefully what I actually wrote and not what you imagine. (Unrelated: please use @.)

Comment: @Did : $arg(-i)$ is actually equal to both $3\pi{}/2$ and $-\pi{}/2$ since "equal" here means "belongs to the same equivalence class modulo $2\pi{}$". As we can see in the end of the proof, from the definition itself of the argument, if $a$ is an argument, $a + 2\pi{}$, $a + 4\pi{}$... are also arguments since the $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions would yield the same results. Maybe a better statement would have been "$\theta_w + \theta_z$ is **an** argument of $wz$".

Comment: You are belaboring the obvious. Unfortunately for your argument (!), the function $\arg$ is usually defined on $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$ with values in $[0,2\pi)$ (or some translate of it). Hence, "from the definition itself of the argument", $\arg(z)$ is a **number** (and no, the numbers $3\pi/2$ and $-\pi/2$ are not equal...).

Comment: @Did with respect to your 1st comment $arg(-i)$ is a set so both $3π/2$ and $−π/2$ are elements of it right? If we are talking about $Argz$ then ya it can be both $3π/2$ and $−π/2$ too since some cases $Argz$ is defined on $(-π,π]$ and as you said also on $[0,2π)$

Comment: What I was trying to say is that $\arg{wz} = \arg{w} + \arg{z}$ is only true if we are taking modulo $2\pi$ if we only want principal values. But it has nothing to do with the corectness of my proof except the last line, where I should have checked is the sum was in $[0, 2\pi[$.

Comment: @Heisenberg If indeed $\arg(z)$ is a set then $\arg(zw)=\arg(z)+\arg(w)$ is rock-solid. The trouble is that in quite a few answers you received, $\arg(z)$ is a **number**, and then the formula is not always true.

Comment: @Traklon This is confusing things again, I am afraid: "argwz=argw+argz is only true if we are taking modulo 2π if we only want principal values". One cannot consider equivalence classes modulo 2π and principal values at the same time, one must choose one or the other. Principal values are *real numbers*, equivalence classes are *subsets of the real line*.

Comment: @Did I added the definition of argz to the question hoping it would resolve any confusions

Comment: @did Yes it works for sets but not always for principal arguments

Comment: @Traklonq the sum need not be in [0,2π[ right?