# Alternative Proof of arg(zw)=arg(z)+arg(w)

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, solution-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof

$$arg(zw)\equiv arg(z)+arg(w) (\text{mod } 2\pi)$$

is a standard property of complex numbers. I know the [proof using the polar form or the exponential form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/925296/proving-argzw-argz-argw).I am attempting to prove it using the $tan^{-1}$ definition of $arg$.

Let there be two complex numbers such that $z=a+bi,w=c+di$. Then, the left hand side equals
$$arg(zw)=arg[(a+bi)(c+di)]=arg[ac-bd+(bc+ad)i)]=tan^{-1} \left[ \frac{bc+ad}{ac-db} \right]$$

Similarly, the right hand side equals:
$$arg(z)+arg(w)=arg(a+bi)+arg(c+di)=tan^{-1}\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)+tan^{-1}\left(\frac{d}{c}\right)$$
Use the property $tan^{-1}(x)+tan^{-1}(y)=tan^{-1}(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}), xy<1$
$$=tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\frac{b}{a}+\frac{d}{c}}{1-\frac{b}{a}\times\frac{d}{c}}\right)=tan^{-1} \left[ \frac{bc+ad}{ac-db}\right]$$

This is under the assumption:

- $tan^{-1}$ will give the correct argument only for complex numbers in the first and fourth quadrant. Hence, assume these conditions are met.
- We need the product of the angles to be less than one. Else the property changes to:

$$tan^{-1}(x)+tan^{-1}(y)=\pi + tan^{-1}(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}), xy>1$$

Is the above proof correct? Can it be generalized to remove the assumptions?

I appreciate comments on stating the property correctly. However, my question is more on generalizing the proof.

Comment: $arg(zw)=arg(z)+arg(w)$ isn't true in general unless you add "mod $(2 \pi)$"

Comment: Consider arg as a multi valued function, and consider values mod (2 pi). So yes, your comment needs to be incorporated.

Comment: Can I simply say that arg(zw) is coterminal with arg(z)+arg(w). I did not understand your comment with respect to "and" should be an exclusive.

Comment: I meant that either you consider arg as a multivalued function **(exclusive) or** work mod $2 \pi$, not both.

Comment: I would prefer to work with coterminal angles. Why do you think that option is not very advisable?

Comment: I simply don't know the term "coterminal angle". I would be happy to have a reference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138926/discussion-between-starlight-and-jean-marie).

Comment: Reference  for coterminal angles https://www.georgebrown.ca/sites/default/files/uploadedfiles/tlc/_documents/coterminal_angles.pdf

Comment: The best way to write the property is $arg(zw)\equiv arg(z)+arg(w)\pmod{2\pi}$, typeset in Latex as `arg(zw) \equiv arg(z)+arg(w) \pmod {2\pi}`. The $\equiv$ sign can be read as _is equivalent to_, and the $\bmod$ sign (with a parenthesis immediately before it that shows it's not an operator) is a qualifier for the equivalence(s) on the left. When reading, there is a pause before _modulo_, and correspondingly a rather large space before the opening parenthesis for$\bmod$.